# raster2pgsql - invalid pointer

Tags: postgis, raster, gdal, postgis-raster, raster2pgsql

I get the following error each time I run the raster2pgsql:

```
[postgres@li1959-236 ~]$ raster2pgsql -I -C -s 4326 -M -F /home/temp/wrf_d02_202005010000.tif grib_test |  psql -d cep
Processing 1/1: /home/temp/wrf_d02_202005010000.tif
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE
free(): invalid pointer
ERROR:  unterminated quoted string at or near "'
```

I converted a band of a Grib into a GeoTIFF and I did nothing else.

My PG version is the 12 and posting 3.0.

Any suggestion?

```
# gdalinfo /home/temp/wrf_d02_202005010000.tif |more
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /home/temp/wrf_d02_202005010000.tif
Size is 393, 348
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (2762460.472548419144005,3366910.845273251645267)
Pixel Size = (7200.000000000000000,-7200.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 2762460.473, 3366910.845) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Lower Left  ( 2762460.473,  861310.845) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Upper Right ( 5592060.473, 3366910.845) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Lower Right ( 5592060.473,  861310.845) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Center      ( 4177260.473, 2114110.845) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Band 1 Block=393x2 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = 2[m] HTGL (Specified height level above ground)
  Metadata:
    GRIB_COMMENT=Temperature [C]
    GRIB_ELEMENT=TMP
    GRIB_FORECAST_SECONDS=259200 sec
    GRIB_REF_TIME=1588032000 sec UTC
    GRIB_SHORT_NAME=2-HTGL
    GRIB_UNIT=[C]
    GRIB_VALID_TIME=1588291200 sec UTC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this problem happen on CENTOS 8. I installed a new machine with CentOS7 and using the same sw versions it worked.